# Large data accociation javascript widget

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, extjs, widget

I am looking for a searchable multiple select javascript widget that can handle filtering large amounts of server-side data for a 1-n relationship.  For instance I have a category and I want to be able to filter through an unassociated list of products and attach them to the category in a user friendly way.  I don't want the unassociated list loaded with the widget - it is too large.  It needs to have a remote search.

I found this: [multiselect](http://yanickrochon.uuuq.com/multiselect/) but I had problems with large sets of data.

Anyone have any ideas where I can find something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ExtJS would be the right tool to go with, because it has a full-featured and extendible grid widget. However a part of what you want to achieve is related to back-end technologies. If you're in favor of Ruby on Rails, you may consider using the [Netzke framework](http://wiki.github.com/skozlov/netzke) to tie front- and back-end parts of your widget together. An example of 1-n relationship is here:

http://netzke-demo.writelesscode.com/basic_app/demo#bossesAndClerksExt